# Looking for SimpleAutocomplete.svelte in my project directory

Tags: sveltekit

I'm using 'simple-svelte-autocomplete' in my project.   I've installed it with 'npm install', and I find it correctly in my node-modules directory.

The only reference to the module in my code is as follows:

Filter.svelte:
`<script> import AutoComplete from 'simple-svelte-autocomplete'; ... </script> <AutoComplete ...> </AutoComplete>`

However, when I run or build my project  (npm run dev)  I get the following error:

```
`Error: Not found: /myproject/SimpleAutocomplete.svelte
at resolve (/myproject_dir/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:480:13)
at resolve (/myproject_dir/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:282:5)
at Object.#options.hooks.handle (/myproject_dir/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/index.js:56:56)
at Module.respond (/myproject_dir/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:279:40)    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)`
```

'myproject' is the name of one of the routes in my svelte application.

I was able to find 'SimpleAutocomplete.svelte' in the following location:
/myproject_dir/node_modules/simple-svelte-autocomplete/src/SimpleAutocomplete.svelte

It's also interesting to know that the AutoComplete functionality works even with the error message.
However, I think that there are some knock-on effects and so I'd like to isolate and fix the error anyway.

Comment: Any luck please? I have the same bug :(

Comment: Sorry, no.  I was able to verify that the error seemed to be causing no issues, (I resolved what I thought were related) and so I'm just living with it.

The error only happens at 'render' time.   If I 'prerender' during the build process then it doesn't exist in the finished package.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your dependency was not installed successfully. Here I suggest you:

1. Take a look https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-svelte-autocomplete
2. check package.json or package-lock.json make sure it is installed.
3. Re-install that package.

I just tried how to import this package like so:

```
<script>
        import AutoComplete from "simple-svelte-autocomplete"

        const colors = ["White", "Red", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Black"]
        let selectedColor
</script>

<AutoComplete items="{colors}" bind:selectedItem="{selectedColor}" />
```

it works properly!